# Formatting texts with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm a newbie. I have the following `xml`:

```
<text>
    <sentence type="grocery">I bought <fruit> apples</fruit> at the grocery store.</sentence>
    <sentence type="grocery">I also bought <fruit> bananas</fruit> at the store.</sentence>
    <sentence>Then, I bought a basket at another store.</sentence>
</text>
```

How can I display the text in the following format `(the fruits should be red or different color)`:

```
"I bought <font color="red">apples</font> at the grocery store."

"I also bought <font color="red">bananas</font> at the story."
```

Here is the xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">



    <xsl:for-each select="text/sentence">

      <p><p> <xsl:value-of select="descendant-or-self::node()[contains(.,'')]" /></p>


    </xsl:for-each>


</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, which is the target format, HTML, PDF, something else_ Find out how to mark up a text in that target format with a certain color and then simply write a template `<xsl:template match="fruit">...</xsl:template>` that contains the right markup.

Comment: The target format is HTML.

Comment: Then check any basic HTML and CSS tutorial on marking up an element with a certain color https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Fundamentals#Color

Comment: Thanks Martin. Would you be able to provide the entire xslt? If I use <xsl:value-of select="sentence">, it only displays "I bought."

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: I have the following xsl:<xsl:template match="/">

   
            
        <xsl:for-each select="text/sentence">
                        
          <p> <xsl:value-of select="descendant-or-self::node()[contains(.,'')]" /></p>
                        
                   
        </xsl:for-each>


    </xsl:template>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: Sorry. just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/text">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="sentence"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sentence"> 
    <p> 
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="fruit"> 
    <span style="color:red;"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span> 
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, will return:

**Result**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>I bought <span style="color:red;"> apples</span> at the grocery store.</p>
        <p>I also bought <span style="color:red;"> bananas</span> at the story.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**rendered as:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michael. Your XSL works! I have another question. What if I only need to display <sentence type="grocery">? Please see the edited xml above. I added an attribute. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Change `<xsl:apply-templates select="sentence"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="sentence[@type='grocery']"/>`.